# Windows Update on Windows 10 doesn't work?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-10

I upgraded from windows 8.1 to windows 10. At first I could access to windows update but after restarting, I can't even open it. Also, Its icon in the all program is gone.

Comment: You can also press the windows key on the keyboard. When the menu pops up, type windows update.  It will list all the programs beginning with windows update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Update is now under Settings:

[image]